# How to add a custom tooltip to a JtextField?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtextfield

sorry for my bad english, I am currently developing an application for a company, I would like to be able to give indications on the information to enter in JtextFields, but the problem is that this indication is sometimes long, so I found a class with a tooltip custom which allows to go to the line in the text of the tooltip but I do not find how to add it to my textfield.
I try this code:

```
JMultiLineToolTip mltt = new JMultiLineToolTip();
    mltt.setTipText("Write an extention or anything you want, if the string apeare in file's name,\n the file will be added in result ");
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(134, 104, 210, 20);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.add(mltt);
    //textField.setToolTipText("Write an extention or anything you want, if the string apeare in file's name,\n the file will be added in result ");
    request.add(textField);
```

here the code of JMultiLineToolTip

```
public class JMultiLineToolTip extends JToolTip {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7813662474312183098L;

public JMultiLineToolTip() {
    updateUI();
}

public void updateUI() {
    setUI(MultiLineToolTipUI.createUI(this));
}

public void setColumns(int columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
    this.fixedwidth = 0;
}

public int getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setFixedWidth(int width) {
    this.fixedwidth = width;
    this.columns = 0;
}

public int getFixedWidth() {
    return fixedwidth;
}

protected int columns = 0;
protected int fixedwidth = 0;
```

}

```
class MultiLineToolTipUI extends BasicToolTipUI {

static MultiLineToolTipUI sharedInstance = new MultiLineToolTipUI();
Font smallFont;
static JToolTip tip;
protected CellRendererPane rendererPane;

private static JTextArea textArea;

public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return sharedInstance;
}

public MultiLineToolTipUI() {
    super();
}

public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    tip = (JToolTip) c;
    rendererPane = new CellRendererPane();
    c.add(rendererPane);
}

public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    super.uninstallUI(c);

    c.remove(rendererPane);
    rendererPane = null;
}

public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Dimension size = c.getSize();
    textArea.setBackground(c.getBackground());
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, textArea, c, 1, 1, size.width - 1, size.height - 1, true);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    String tipText = ((JToolTip) c).getTipText();
    if (tipText == null) return new Dimension(0, 0);
    textArea = new JTextArea(tipText);
    rendererPane.removeAll();
    rendererPane.add(textArea);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    int width = ((JMultiLineToolTip) c).getFixedWidth();
    int columns = ((JMultiLineToolTip) c).getColumns();

    if (columns > 0) {
        textArea.setColumns(columns);
        textArea.setSize(0, 0);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setSize(textArea.getPreferredSize());
    } else if (width > 0) {
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        Dimension d = textArea.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = width;
        d.height++;
        textArea.setSize(d);
    } else
        textArea.setLineWrap(false);

    Dimension dim = textArea.getPreferredSize();

    dim.height += 1;
    dim.width += 1;
    return dim;
}

public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c) {
    return getPreferredSize(c);
}

public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c) {
    return getPreferredSize(c);
}
```

Comment: Please post your question in english.

Comment: Yes sorry it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you took this code from [Yoshiko-app](https://github.com/ls-cwi/yoshiko-app/tree/master/src/main/java/com/yoshiko/internal/view), there are examples on this same [github](https://github.com/ls-cwi/yoshiko-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yoshiko/internal/view/YoshikoMainPanel.java#L182):

```
String pathTip = "Sets the tmp path.";
JPanel pathPanel = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
        return new JMultiLineToolTip();
    }
};
pathPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pathPanel.setToolTipText(pathTip);
```

You jsut need to adapt this code for JtextField

Comment: Thanks you it work perfectly with this code : textField = new JTextField() {
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
           return new JMultiLineToolTip();
       }
   };

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `createTooltip` method of your textfield :

```
textField = new JTextField() {
  public JToolTip createToolTip() {
    mltt.setComponent(this);
    return mltt;
  }
};
```

Note that the tooltip object will have to be declared `final`, so that it can be used in the above anonymous class :

```
final JMultiLineToolTip mltt = new JMultiLineToolTip();
```